# Trouble with discord bot embeds

Tags: discord.js

First I'd like to point out that I just started learning discord.js a month ago, so my code is probably all wrong and I understand that.

I'm trying to learn how to write embeds, but a whole ton of stuff doesn't work, mainly because I don't know where to put everything.

In my main js file, I have the following:

```js
} else if (command == 'embed') {
    client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args);
}
```

And in my embed.js file, I have all of this code which doesn't work at all.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    description: 'example embed.',
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
        .setDescription('Some description here')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
        .addFields({
            name: 'Regular field title',
            value: 'Some value here'
        }, {
            name: '\u200B',
            value: '\u200B'
        }, {
            name: 'Inline field title',
            value: 'Some value here',
            inline: true
        }, {
            name: 'Inline field title',
            value: 'Some value here',
            inline: true
        }, )
        .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

    channel.send(exampleEmbed);
}
```

Thank you for listening to this. I'd love for anyone to help.

Comment: What does "doesn't work at all" mean? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to export a [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) in the `module.exports`, but you need to export a function called `execute`.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'embed',
    description: 'example embed.',
    execute: (message, args) => {
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
        .setDescription('Some description here')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
        .addFields({
            name: 'Regular field title',
            value: 'Some value here'
        }, {
            name: '\u200B',
            value: '\u200B'
        }, {
            name: 'Inline field title',
            value: 'Some value here',
            inline: true
        }, {
            name: 'Inline field title',
            value: 'Some value here',
            inline: true
        }, )
        .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

        message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused now, as I have fixed all this, and no error messages show up, however, when I type the command, the bot still doesn't respond.

Comment: Add a `console.log("test")` at the beginning of the `execute` function, right before `const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()` and tell me if you see "test" in the console when executing the command.

Comment: no test,  only "bot is working" and how many servers it is running in. oh dear

Comment: Alright. It'd be best if we would continue this discussion in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221049/).